# Bouncing-ball simulation

Tags: c, simulation

I posted a couple questions about a week ago, but have almost gotten it working. This program is supposed to simulate the following:

1. Ask the user how many balls to drop
2. Drop one ball at a time
3. Allow it to bounce ten times moving either once to the right or once to the left each bounce
4. Then print out the even numbers (since a ball could never land on an odd) -10 - 10 with a 'o' to represent each ball.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

/* Prototype for drop_Balls, int parameter is number of balls being dropped */
void drop_balls(int); 

/* Gets the number of balls that need to be dropped by the user */
int get_num_balls(); 

int main()
{
    drop_balls(get_num_balls());
}

int get_num_balls()   
{
    int num_balls;
    printf("How many balls should be dropped? ");
    scanf("%d", &num_balls);
    /* Ensure that it is atleast one ball */
    while(num_balls <= 0) 
    {
        printf("You have to drop at least one ball! \n ");
        printf("How many balls should be dropped? ");
        scanf("%d", &num_balls);
    }
    /* Return the number of balls that will be dropped */
    return num_balls; 
}

void drop_balls(int num_balls)
{
    /* Keeps track of how many balls landed where */
    int ball_count[21]; 
    /* What number ball are we on */
    int ball_num = 0; 
    /* Seed the generator */
    srand(time(NULL)); 
    /* Do the correct # of balls */
    for(ball_num = 0; ball_num < num_balls; ball_num++ ) 
    {
        /* Start at 10 since its the middle of 21 */
        int starting_point = 10; 
        /* Bounce each ball 10 times */
        for(starting_point = 10; starting_point > 0; starting_point--) 
        {
           int number;
           /* Create a random integer between 1-100 */
           number = rand() % 100; 
            /* If its less than 50 bounce to the right once */
           if(number >= 50) 
           {
               starting_point++;
           }
           /* If its greater than 50, bounce to the left once */
           else 
           {
               starting_point--;
           }
        }
        /* Add one to simulate one ball landing there */
        ball_count[starting_point]++;  
    }

    /* Start at the -10 spot */
    int ball_place = -10; 
    int x;
    /* Go through the 21 spots, but skip the odd ones, since they never get balls */
    for(x = 0; x < 20; x+2)
    {
        printf("\n %d: ", ball_place);
        int l = 0;
        /* Print out an 'o' for each ball */
        for(l = 0; l < ball_count[x]; l++)
        {
            printf("o");
        }
        /* Increase the spot, taking it from -10 - 10 */
        ball_place = ball_place + 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what's the question? Is your code working the way you want it to? If not, then your question is off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

**Comments**

You should use `//` comments for single-line comments.

I am not sure you are using comments properly. Comments shouldn't explain how, it should explain why.

```
/* Prototype for drop_Balls, int parameter is number of balls being dropped */
void drop_balls(int);
```

One can see that this is a prototype. `void drop_balls(int number_of_balls);` would probably provide as much information in a more compact way.

```
/* Return the number of balls that will be dropped */
return num_balls;
```

This does not look like a useful comment to me.

```
/* Keeps track of how many balls landed where */
int ball_count[21];
```

A bit of explanation on the `21` here would be useful... but it is not provided.

This leads me to the next section:

**Magic numbers**

You probably don't want to have hard-coded numbers all over the place. You could create a constant with value 21 and then:

- `starting_point = 10` would become `starting_point = N /2`.
- `for(x = 0; x < 20; x+2)` would become `for(x = 0; x < N; x+2)`.
- `int ball_place = -10;` would become `int ball_place = - N/2;`

**Code organisation**

It would probably be better now to call `srand` in `rand_balls` as it shouldn't be its responsibility. You can do it from `main()` if you want.

Define variable in the smallest possible scope. For instance:

```
for(int ball_num = 0; ball_num < num_balls; ball_num++ )
```

Also, how is this loop:

```
for(starting_point = 10; starting_point > 0; starting_point--)
```

supposed to behave?  Don't we always have the variable set to 0 or -1 at the end?

Comment: I agree with what you said about the commenting, I will also go through and change them to make more sense once I get it working. The constants I know make it look sloppy, I was going to go through and change that once I got everything working. That loop moves it once to the left or right every pass through, so I think its doing what its supposed to.

Comment: Can you explain your advice, "You should use `//` comments for single-line comments."? What if the OP needs the code to compile with the `-ansi` flag?

Comment: Shouldn't `srand()` always be called in `main()`?  It doesn't look like it should be an option.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Josay's answer:

This code contains some duplication which you can avoid:

```
printf("How many balls should be dropped? ");
scanf("%d", &num_balls);
/* Ensure that it is atleast one ball */
while(num_balls <= 0) 
{
    printf("You have to drop at least one ball! \n ");
    printf("How many balls should be dropped? ");
    scanf("%d", &num_balls);
}
```

Either refactor for the number of balls into it's own method:

```
int ask_for_number_of_balls()
{
    printf("How many balls should be dropped? ");
    scanf("%d", &num_balls);
}
```

And then your loop becomes:

```
int num_balls = ask_for_number_of_balls();
while (num_balls <= 0)
{
    printf("You have to drop at least one ball! \n ");
    num_balls = ask_for_number_of_balls();
}
```

Or you get a bit clever:

```
int num_balls = -1;
while (1)
{
    printf("How many balls should be dropped? ");
    scanf("%d", &num_balls);
    if (num_balls > 0) { break; }
    printf("You have to drop at least one ball! \n ");
}
```

I would probably prefer the refactored method over clever (clever is harder to read and maintain).

I'm not sure about this loop:

```
for(starting_point = 10; starting_point > 0; starting_point--)
```

You randomly add one or subtract one from `starting_point`, but the running condition for that loop is `starting_point > 0`. So, as long as the starting point is greater than 0, this loop will run. This means that at the end, `starting_point` will always be 0 afterwards (not to mention that your loop could run for a long time if your random numbers happen to be greater than 50 most of the time).